# "No matching provisioning profiles" when Submitting App to App Store in XCode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, app-store-connect

I have been trying to submit an update to my app in the app store and for the past 12 hours. I keep encountering this message in Xcode 7.3.

[image]

I have deleted all distribution provisioning profiles, recreated them, remade my app ids, removed them from xcode, re-downloaded them to xcode etc... I keep getting this message. The app is already in the app store. Any suggestions on what I can try? Building the app is easier then submitting the app. Thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked for me except the following simple solution. What resolved the issue was manually setting Provisioning Profile for Debug and Release to the appropriate values, as opposed to choosing Automatic (i.e., set values to your development and distribution provisioning profiles) for each of my targets. I did this for the main app, today extension, watchkit extension and watchkit app. After that all works as expected. Thanks for everybody's contribution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have this error before and solved it by simple steps:-

1-xCode->Preferences->Accounts choose your Apple developer account-> View Details> right click on provision profiles and choose show in finder and delete all provision profiles.

2-Remove your Developer account.

3-Remove all Certification from Key Chain access.

4-Restart your Mac.

5-Check your certifications and provision profiles in your Apple Developer Account and be sure its working correct.

6-Open your xCode and add your Developer account and be sure that you download all provision profiles.

7-Restart your Mac and open xCode again and push your App to iTunes Connect.

I hope I help you.

Comment: Thank you iOS BadBoy. I will try this later on (not in front of my machine) and report back if this worked.

Comment: Nothing worked for me except the following simple solution. What resolved the issue was manually setting Provisioning Profile for Debug and Release to the appropriate values, as opposed to choosing Automatic (i.e., set values to your development and distribution provisioning profiles) for each of my targets. I did this for the main app, today extension, watchkit extension and watchkit app. After that all works as expected. Thanks for everybody's contribution.

Comment: Agreed - delete everything and start again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the right way for doing it, but I also had this problem when trying to submit an app with a watch kit component. What I did was create different provisioning profiles for each target.

1) The provisioning profile that you already have for your actual app.

2) Provisioning profile for the WatchKit target.

3) Provisioning profile for the WatchKit Extension.

I added all three of these to the Xcode project and went to the Build Settings tab for each target to set the provisioning profile for each target separately.  Then I was able to submit my app without any warnings or errors.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have the following provisioning profiles:1. Main app 2. Widget 3. Watch Kit App 4 Watch Kit Extension In the code signing I see it setup as iOS Developer. And provisioning as Automatic. Should that be changed maybe?

Comment: What you need to do is delete all four of those provisioning profiles and make them all again, but re-name them to something different bc downloading with the same name seems to give a problem.  Then re-assign each provisioning profile and upload

Comment: Thanks MSU_Bulldog. When you say rename, are you referring to the app id or the name of the provisioning profile? My understanding is that the appId should never change.

Comment: Change the name of the provisioning profile... NOT the appID

Comment: Thank you MSU_Bulldog. I will try this later on (not in front of my machine) and report back if this worked.

Comment: Nothing worked for me except the following simple solution. What resolved the issue was manually setting Provisioning Profile for Debug and Release to the appropriate values, as opposed to choosing Automatic (i.e., set values to your development and distribution provisioning profiles) for each of my targets. I did this for the main app, today extension, watchkit extension and watchkit app. After that all works as expected. Thanks for everybody's contribution.

Comment: @BasriHassan thats exactly what I told you to do in my answer, you can accept it as the correct answer